# Conditions for toggleClass

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want my links to highlight when I mouseover them, which I've managed.

But I also want the first item to be already highlighted - but become un-highlighted when I mouseout.

Additionally, if the mouseouts all links, I'd like the last link (that was mouseover) to remain highlighted. I'm too much of a noob to figure out how to do this, I'm hoping someone can guide me. Many thanks in advance. :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menuLink").hover(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("menuLinkFocus menuLink");
    });
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: zx_spectrum-7;
  src: url(zx_spectrum-7.ttf);
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.bg {
  background-color: #e0e0ef;
  font-family: zx_spectrum-7;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#screen {
  height: 556px;
  width: 720p1;
  background-color: #e0e0ef;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#screenFooter {
  height: 20px;
  width: 720px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu {
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
  background-image: url(images/menu.jpg);
  height: 96px;
  width: 205px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  line-height: 16px;
  line-width: 201px;
}

#menu li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top:16px;
  padding-left:16px;
  color:#343434;
}

.menuLink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #343434;
  display: block;
  width: 201px;
}

.menuLinkFocus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #34efef;
  color: #343434;
  display: block;
  width: 187px;
  margin-left: -14px;
  padding-left: 14px;
}

.menuLinkStart {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #34efef;
  color: #343434;
  display: block;
  width: 187px;
  margin-left: -14px;
  padding-left: 14px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg">
  <div id="screen">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="menuLinkFocus">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menuLink">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menuLink">Item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menuLink">Item 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--End Menu-->
  </div>
  <!--End Screen-->
  <div id="screenFooter">Footer text hereLtd</div>
```

Comment: can you create the demo?

Comment: It's there. I had some padding which meant you couldn't see it, got rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, this will work for you fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<style type="text/css">

ul.mylinks{
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 100px;
}

ul.mylinks li{
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}

ul.mylinks li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:orange;
 font-family: monospace;
 font-size:20px;
}

#id1{
 background-color: gray;
}


</style>
</head>



<body>

<ul class="mylinks">
 <li id="id1"><a href="">link 1111</a></li>
 <li id="id2"><a href="">link 2222</a></li>
 <li id="id3"><a href="">link 3333</a></li>
 <li id="id4"><a href="">link 4444</a></li>
 <li id="id5"><a href="">link 5555</a></li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul.mylinks li").mouseenter(function(){
   $("ul.mylinks li:first-child").css({"background-color":"white"});
  });

  $("ul.mylinks li").mouseenter(function(){
   var get_theid = $(this).attr('id');
   var theid = "#"+get_theid;
   $(theid).css({"background-color":"gray"});
   $('li:not('+theid+')').css({"background-color":"white"});
//above line means the 'id' name 'not' 'equal' to the mouse entered  
  });

  
 });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

good luck.

Comment: Many thanks, this is a very elegant answer. I was trying to think of a way to do it using variables, but I'm not yet versed enough to do it. One quick question if I may. Where can I find out more about this line: ('li:not('+theid+')'), I don't really understand what has happened there. Thank you again.

Comment: I just edited my reply to ask a quick quesiton, I'd be most grateful if you could point me in the right direction, preferably at W3, where I've been leaning. Thanks again. :)

Comment: yep, W3S is nice place to do learn and do your own things. self practice is most important. good luck again

Comment: sorry, you have asked for question. `('li:not('+theid+')')` means, before this line we get the `current id`, which user mouse entered, and with `('li:not('+theid+')')` this code , we get other `id` s which not mouse entered at the moment  and put them highlight to white.

Comment: Got it. Thank you again. It's tough but extremely rewarding, learning to code - just wish I'd started a little younger. :D

Answer (score 2):

Change the code to just use `mouseenter` so that it doesn't change back on mouseeleave like it would with jQuery's `hover()`, and then trigger the event on the first element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menuLink").on('mouseenter', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("menuLinkFocus menuLink")
             .closest('li')
             .siblings()
             .find('a')
             .addClass('menuLink')
             .removeClass('menuLinkFocus');
  }).first().trigger('mouseenter');
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
@font-face {
  font-family: zx_spectrum-7;
  src: url(zx_spectrum-7.ttf);
}
* {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
.bg {
  background-color: #e0e0ef;
  font-family: zx_spectrum-7;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#screen {
  height: 556px;
  width: 720p1;
  background-color: #e0e0ef;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
#screenFooter {
  height: 20px;
  width: 720px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu {
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
  background-image: url(images/menu.jpg);
  height: 96px;
  width: 205px;
  padding-right: 257.5px;
  padding-left: 257.5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  padding-bottom: 232px;
  line-height: 16px;
  line-width: 201px;
}
#menu li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
padding-top:16px;
 padding-left:16px;
 color:#343434;

}
.menuLink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #343434;
  display: block;
  width: 201px;
}
.menuLinkFocus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #34efef;
  color: #343434;
  display: block;
  width: 187px;
  margin-left: -14px;
  padding-left: 14px;
}
.menuLinkStart {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #34efef;
  color: #343434;
  display: block;
  width: 187px;
  margin-left: -14px;
  padding-left: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="screen">
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="menuLink">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menuLink">Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menuLink">Item 3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menuLink">Item 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--End Menu-->
</div>
<!--End Screen-->
<div id="screenFooter">Footer text hereLtd</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It will take me some time to work out what you did, but it works perfectly! I have a long way to go before I understand any of this properly. Big thanks again! :)

Comment: @Cuckoo - you're welcome, remember to accept the answer.